# how to print a 2d array timetable?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package javaapplication18;

public class JavaApplication18 {


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String weekdays[][] = new String[7][0];
       weekdays[1][0] = "mon";
       weekdays[2][0] = "tue";
       weekdays[3][0] = "wed";
       weekdays[4][0] = "thur";
       weekdays[5][0] = "fri";
       weekdays[6][0] = "sat";
       String hours[][] = new String[0][5];
       hours[0][1] = "9:30";
       hours[0][2] = "10:30";
       hours[0][3] = "11:30";
       hours[0][4] = "12:30";
       System.out.println(weekdays[7][0]);
   }

}
```

when i compiled it it gives error saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at javaapplication18.JavaApplication18.main(JavaApplication18.java:8)
how do i rectify this ?

Comment: change to System.out.println(weekdays[6][0]);

Comment: you declare it like this `String[7][0]`. In fact your now facing a `0` size array where you can´t store elements.

Comment: Why not just `String weekdays[] = new String[7];`? Why do you need 2-dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Change the array size in declaration of array. size 0 should be 1.

When you are declaring an array, the index should be at least one. Because it tells how many space it should allocate in memory. But when you are using array latter, the index is 0 based. If you declare `a[7][1]`, the last array element would be `a[6][0]`.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String weekdays[][] = new String[7][1];
       weekdays[0][0] = "sun";
       weekdays[1][0] = "mon";
       weekdays[2][0] = "tue";
       weekdays[3][0] = "wed";
       weekdays[4][0] = "thur";
       weekdays[5][0] = "fri";
       weekdays[6][0] = "sat";

       String hours[][] = new String[1][5];
       hours[0][1] = "9:30";
       hours[0][2] = "10:30";
       hours[0][3] = "11:30";
       hours[0][4] = "12:30";
       System.out.println(weekdays[6][0]); // sat
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //way 1
    String weekdays[][] = new String[7][];
    weekdays[0] = new String[] { "sun" };
    weekdays[1] = new String[] { "mon" };
    weekdays[2] = new String[] { "tue" };
    weekdays[3] = new String[] { "wed" };
    weekdays[4] = new String[] { "thur" };
    weekdays[5] = new String[] { "fri" };
    weekdays[6] = new String[] { "sat" };

    //way 2
    String hours[][] = new String[1][5];
    hours[0][0] = "8:30";
    hours[0][1] = "9:30";
    hours[0][2] = "10:30";
    hours[0][3] = "11:30";
    hours[0][4] = "12:30";
    System.out.println(weekdays[1][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change array size as well as 6 instead of 7 in weekdays array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String weekdays[][] = new String[7][1];
        weekdays[0][0] = "sun";
        weekdays[1][0] = "mon";
        weekdays[2][0] = "tue";
        weekdays[3][0] = "wed";
        weekdays[4][0] = "thur";
        weekdays[5][0] = "fri";
        weekdays[6][0] = "sat";

        String hours[][] = new String[1][5];
        hours[0][1] = "9:30";
        hours[0][2] = "10:30";
        hours[0][3] = "11:30";
        hours[0][4] = "12:30";
        System.out.println(weekdays[6][0]);
    }
```

//answer after OPs comment

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String weekdays[][] = new String[7][7];
        weekdays[0][0] = "sun";

        weekdays[0][1] = "9:30";
        weekdays[0][2] = "10:30";
        weekdays[0][3] = "11:30";

        weekdays[1][0] = "mon";

        weekdays[1][1] = "9:30";
        weekdays[1][2] = "10:30";
        weekdays[1][3] = "11:30";

        weekdays[2][0] = "tue";

        weekdays[2][1] = "9:30";
        weekdays[2][2] = "10:30";
        weekdays[2][3] = "11:30";

        weekdays[3][0] = "wed";

        weekdays[3][1] = "9:30";
        weekdays[3][2] = "10:30";
        weekdays[3][3] = "11:30";

        weekdays[4][0] = "thur";

        weekdays[4][1] = "9:30";
        weekdays[4][2] = "10:30";
        weekdays[4][3] = "11:30";

        weekdays[5][0] = "fri";

        weekdays[5][1] = "9:30";
        weekdays[5][2] = "10:30";
        weekdays[5][3] = "11:30";

        weekdays[6][0] = "sat";

        weekdays[6][1] = "9:30";
        weekdays[6][2] = "10:30";
        weekdays[6][3] = "11:30";

        String hours[][] = new String[1][5];
        hours[0][1] = "9:30";
        hours[0][2] = "10:30";
        hours[0][3] = "11:30";
        hours[0][4] = "12:30";

        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 7) {
            System.out.print("\t" + weekdays[i][j]);
            j++;
            if (j > 3) {
                j = 0;
                i++;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u all...!!!!...really appreciated ur help guys.....the weekdays are printing but hours not.....i wanted like this                                                                              8 :30  9:30  10:30  11:30
mon 
tue
wed
thur
fri
sat    ..........timings should be on 1st row(i.e,0th row) and days should be in 1st column(i.e,0th column)........im new to prgrmng i dont knw how to print a array like this...??

Comment: Please find my answer after //answer after OPs comment code, it might help

Answer (score 0):

First, the error you are getting is Runtime error and it should not happen during compilation time.
Second, in order to print an array you need to iterate over it, same goes for 2d arrays.

Your code should be like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < weekdays.length ; i++ ){
        for ( int j = 0;  j < weekdays[j].length ; j++ ){
            System.out.println(weekdays[i][j]);
        }
    }
```